# Is it required for AppStore to use SSL when sending Username/Password to a server

Tags: iphone, objective-c, authentication, passwords

I am having a nightmare at the minute since Apple have axed OpenSSL (building a server for major the OSs).

I have a logon screen on my app that sends a user name and password to the server(C++ boost) that then will return a session key.

What should I do to send the password to the server and have apple accept my app? Is SSL the only way to do it. If so could someone please point me in the direction of a good guide or xcode project for SSL sockets on the iphone. There doesn't seem to be much at all on the net about it but almost all apps must do it.

Comment: I dont really get what your problem is. SSL is a standard... nothing language specific about it

Comment: Is there nothing you can point my in the direction of. Why is there nothing on Apples Docs about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no SSL isnt strictly required but but I wouldnt trust any app that does not use secure communication.

Comment: I was hoping that iOS would be similar/compatible with the way SSL works with boost. http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/doc/html/boost_asio/example/ssl/client.cpp

Comment: I dont really get what your problem is. SSL is a standard... nothing language specific about it

Comment: I was expecting to create an SSL socket like you would in java or c boost.

Comment: I'm looking at this. http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.co.uk/2010/05/nsstream-tcp-and-ssl.html but I thought I would get to deal with the handshake myself. Or is that all dealt with by NSStream